# Major glitch with EE3 and multiple file fields

Tags: grid, ee3, files

I've got a channel that uses a file field for a logo and another file field for a building beauty shot. In EE3, if I change the image on one field, then change the file on the other, it change BOTH to the same image. The only workaround I can find is to change one, save, then change the other and save.

Even worse is to use this with the Grid setup, which I use for photo albums. Say I finally get 20 images added to an album (add 1, save, add 2, save, etc). If I try to edit multiple images between saves, it changes all the images I edited to the same image. So if I change image2, then image15, then image12, all three change.

This is absurd! Is anyone else seeing this (hopefully fixed it), or is it just my install?

EE3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. This is a known bug in 3.4.1 and is supposed to have been fixed in 3.4.2. I will update and confirm.

Comment: confirmed. Updating to 3.4.2 fixed this bug.